# DFS algorithm: 'list' object has no attribute 'depth'

Tags: python, algorithm

I use python to realize the DFS search algorithm but when I ran the code it said"  'list' object has no attribute 'depth' ".Actually, the object 'node' in my code is an instance of the class Nodes, which will have the attribute 'depth' as I definite before.
Here is my code:

```
import numpy as np  
class Nodes():   # definite a nodes class. It contains state/parent/depth/action properties 'action' means it is generated by which action, which includes 'UP, DOWN, RIGHT, LEFT'

    def __init__(self, state, parent=None, depth=0, action=None):
        self.state = state
        self.parent = parent
        self.depth = depth
        self.action = action
    #  ....

    def DFS(self, goal, limit):
        opentable = []
        opentable.append(self)
        while True:
            if len(opentable) > 0:
                node = opentable.pop(0)
            if node.depth < limit:   # the problem is here
                if (node.state == goal).all():
                    moves = []
                    temp = node
                    i = 0
                    while True:
                        moves.insert(i, temp.action)
                        if temp.depth == 1:
                            break
                        temp = temp.parent
                        i += 1
                     return moves
                 opentable.append(node.generatenodes())
                 opentable.reverse()


if __name__ == '__main__':
     initial = np.array([[0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0, 0],['A', 'B', 'C', 'G']])
     start = Nodes(initial)
     goal = np.array([[0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 'A', 0, 0], [0, 'B', 0, 0],[0, 'C', 0, 'G']])
     start.DFS(goal, 8)
```

Comment: `node.generatenodes()` must be returning a list which you append to `opentable`. When you `pop` it into `node` you then expect `node` to be a `Nodes` object with `depth`, but it's a `list` object, with no `depth`.

Comment: Maybe you should say `opentable.extend(node.generatenodes())` instead of `append`.

Comment: Yes! That is the problem. Thank you~~